# Logical file groups/folders in IntelliJ

Tags: ide, intellij-idea

I just created a project, and I notice immediately that I can't seem to right-click on my src folder and create a logical file group/folder within the project view.

In many IDEs, I can arbitrarily organize source files in groups/folders.  These grouping help me organize my business process and data access layers appropriately.

How do I do the same in IntelliJ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure what the exact equivalent to what you're thinking is, or if there even is one.

IntelliJ has a notion of "scopes".  Under the Project/navigation view, click the configure dropdown and choose "Edit Scopes...".  From this window, you can define a pattern to include certain files from your project.

For instance, all of my DAOs are in packages called `my.company.<feature>.persistence`.  I create a scope called "DAOs" with the pattern `src[myProject]:my.company.*.persistence.*`.  Now when I choose "DAOs" from the Project view dropdown, I see a filtered view of the project.  I haven't found a way to show that filtered view alongside other scopes at the same time, however.

These scopes can also be shared, and they can be used to narrow down searches.  They are similar in many ways to Eclipse's working sets.

Many scopes are defined implicitly, like Test and Production, Changed Files, VCS changesets, etc.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response.  I have not found anything better than your recommendation on scopes via Google.  Seems like this feature doesn't exist in IntelliJ.

Comment: @Brett, you can also try the **Favorites** view.